# iOS: OneSignal presentAppSettings() does not exist

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

I'm setting up a button that should open the app notification preferences. I'm using OneSignal and according to their documentation, they have a presentAppSettings() method. However when I write the following:

```
@IBAction func enableNotificationsTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    OneSignal.presentAppSettings()
}
```

I get an error saying "Type 'OneSignal' has no member 'presentAppSettings'"

I have added

```
import OneSignal
```

at the top but the method just isn't there.

Is there a different way of doing this?

I'm using Swift 4.2 for iOS 12.4 in Xcode 11.
I'm using OneSignal with Cocoapods

```
pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.6.2', '< 3.0'
```

Comment: You mean you want to open permission popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own function like the following:

```
func presentAppSettings() {
    if let url = NSURL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) as URL? {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString):

> The system launches the Settings app and displays the app’s custom settings, if it has any.